# Correct use of sub-entries with glossaries package

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries

I am writing my thesis and I am including a glossary. I am trying to nest some definitions under a "parent" definition. For example, I first define a *mass* and then define *categorical mass* whose parent is *mass*.

I have two problems with the output. First, it glues the definition of *categorical mass* to that of *mass* without leaving a space (See the red circle in the image)... Second, there is no explicit mention of *categorical mass* in the definition.

How can I solve this two problems?

---

### [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{mass}
{
    name={mass function},
    description={A basic belief assingnment (BBA)},
}
\newglossaryentry{categorical}
{
    name={categorical mass function},
    description={A mass function with only one focal set},
    parent=mass
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{something}
we use a \gls{categorical} which is a special case of \gls{mass}

\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the default *glossary style* does not support sub-entries.

You could, for example, use the `index` style. This solves both your problems.

[image: Glossary with sub-entry]

The manual explains:

> **index** The index style is similar to the way indices are usually formatted
>   in that it has a hierarchical structure up to three levels (the
>   main level plus two sub-levels). The name is typeset in bold,
>   and if the symbol is present it is set in parentheses after the
>   name and before the description. Sub-entries are indented and
>   also include the name, the symbol in brackets (if present) and
>   the description. Groups are separated using \indexspace.

And here is the code. (I changed the documentclass to scrartcle so you can see all glossaries on one page.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{mass}
{
    name={mass function},
    description={A basic belief assingnment (BBA)},
}
\newglossaryentry{categorical}
{
    name={categorical mass function},
    description={A mass function with only one focal set},
    parent=mass
}

\begin{document}

we use a \gls{categorical} which is a special case of \gls{mass}

\printglossary[type=main]

\glossarystyle{index}  % chose style here
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

For more details consult the manual `glossaries-user.pdf`, which explains the options for glossary styles in detail in Chapter 15.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly. However, that made me discover a glitch in the glossaries package... He doesn't like when I include a "=" sign in the Symbol field. I posted a question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67796/alternative-command-for-the-equal-sign) where I explain the details and cry for help! Take a look if you have some time. Thanks again!