# Problem with "equal" sign and glossary entry definition

Tags: glossaries, math-operators

I am using glossaries package and I encountered a problem in the *symbol* field. When I define it as `$m=1$` I get the following error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6 \end{theglossary}
                     \glossarypostamble
```

After carefull analysis I discovered that if I remove the equal sign `=`, everything works perfectly. But I have to use the equal sign... Is there an alternative symbol for the equal sign?

If I change the field *symbol* from `$m=1$` to  `$m *(alternative equal sign)* 1$`, my glossary should compile correctly.

Here is a MWE, change the *symbol* field and you'll see the magic... (output after the MWE)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{vacuous}
{
    name={vacuous},
    description={A mass whose bla bla bla},
    symbol=$m=1$,
}

\begin{document}

\gls{vacuous}

\glossarystyle{index}  % chose style here
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The equal sign isn't directly the problem. The option symbol get his meaning by the key. If a key has a special symbol or something like this you must use extra curly brackets to protect the argument:

```
symbol={$m=1$},
```

You see it's the same matter as you uses for `name` or `description`.

Here the mwe:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{vacuous}
{
    name={vacuous},
    description={A mass whose bla bla bla},
    symbol={$m=1$},
}

\begin{document}

\gls{vacuous}

\glossarystyle{index}  % chose style here
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, that is a unexpected but very good solution. Thank you

Comment: @FelipeAguirre: Why unexpected? ;-)

Comment: Because I was sure that the problem was the glossaries package, but it turned out to be me the problem :D
I actually was thinking about changing the title and rephrase the question. After your answer I fill it'll be more constructive for the community if I change it. What do you think?

Comment: @FelipeAguirre: I think it's a great idea.